# PHP get link from txtfile, unset this link inside the array and get random array value

Tags: php

I'm trying to load a website url from a textfile, then unset this string from an array and pick a random website from the array.

But once I try to access the array from my function the array would return NULL, does someone know where my mistake is located at?

My current code looks like the following:

```
<?php

    $activeFile = 'activeSite.txt';

    $sites = array(
        'http://wwww.google.com',
        'http://www.ebay.com',
        'http://www.icloud.com',
        'http://www.hackforums.net',
        'http://www.randomsite.com'
    );

    function getActiveSite($file)
    {
        $activeSite = file_get_contents($file, true);
        return $activeSite;
    }

    function unsetActiveSite($activeSite)
    {
        if(($key = array_search($activeSite, $sites)) !== false) 
        {
            unset($sites[$key]);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function updateActiveSite($activeFile)
    {
        $activeWebsite = getActiveSite($activeFile);

        if(!empty($activeWebsite)) 
        {
            $unsetActive = unsetActiveSite($activeWebsite);

            if($unsetActive == true)
            {
                $randomSite = $sites[array_rand($sites)];
                return $randomSite;
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Could not unset the active website.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo $activeWebsite . ' did not contain any active website.';
        }
    }

    $result = updateActiveSite($activeFile);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: You have an error here : `$randomSite = $sites[array_rand($sites)];`. The variable $sites doesn't exist.

Comment: But the array outside the function is called $sites

Comment: exactly. its **outside** the function. [variable scopes in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sites is not avaliable in unsetActiveSite function you need to create a function called "getSites" which return the $sites array and use it in unsetActiveSite

```
function getSites(){
    $sites = [
        'http://wwww.google.com',
        'http://www.ebay.com',
        'http://www.icloud.com',
        'http://www.hackforums.net',
        'http://www.randomsite.com'
    ];
return $sites;
}
function unsetActiveSite($activeSite)
{
 $sites = getSites();
    if(($key = array_search($activeSite, $sites)) !== false) 
    {
        unset($sites[$key]);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```